# Ajax form duplicating when submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm trying to create a chat application and I know people already asked this question but it doesn't seem to fix my problem.

I've already tried to add a `beforeSend` function but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

HTML Code:

```html
<form method="post" id="message_form" action="insert_msg.php">
      <textarea placeholder="Type your message..." style="width: 550px;" id="messagea" name="messagea"></textarea>
      <div id="galilei">
        <button class="msg_send_btn" type="submit" name="send_msg" onclick="ref(); SubmitFormData();"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Ajax Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#msg_history').load('msg_history.php');
    }, 500);
  });

  function ref() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#message_form').load('form.php');
    }, 500);
  });
  }

  function scroll() {
    $(".msg_history").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "slow");
      return false;
  }

  function SubmitFormData() {
    var frm = $('#message_form');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"insert_msg.php",
            data: frm.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
              $('#galilei').html("Ajax Request is Processing!");
            },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
  }
```

I expected it to not duplicate, like I can say "Hey" and it only stores 1 "Hey" in the database. But, when I submit a message say, "Hello." it stores 1 "Hello" in the database as usual. But, when I message another, let's say "Wow" it stores 2 Wows in the database and etc...

Comment: You are adding a new submit event listener every time `SubmitFormData()` gets called. Each listener will send it's own request. A simple fix is don't call it in the `onclick` and only call it once when page loads

Comment: charlietfl, that seems to have fixed it, but now, it sends me to the insert_msg.php page so... can you help me?

Comment: Sounds like you only removed from button but didn't call the function when page loads...so  the default form submit process is occurring

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick` of your html, so it looks like this:

```
<form method="post" id="message_form" action="insert_msg.php">
      <textarea placeholder="Type your message..." style="width: 550px;" id="messagea" name="messagea"></textarea>
      <div id="galilei">
        <button class="msg_send_btn" type="submit" name="send_msg"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
</form>
```

And change your JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#msg_history').load('msg_history.php');
    }, 500);
  });

  $(document).on('submit', '#message_form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      method:"POST",
      url:"insert_msg.php",
      data: frm.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#galilei').html("Ajax Request is Processing!");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $('#message_form').load('form.php');
      }
    });
  });

  function scroll() {
    $(".msg_history").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "slow");
      return false;
  }
}
```

**Explanation**
We add a listener to the document to listen for the form submit event and intercept it. Then we send that data by ajax. Only once this is done we display the form again. I personally would not remove the form from the DOM, but simply hide it, like for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#msg_history').load('msg_history.php');
    }, 500);
  });

  $('#message_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $(this);
    var message = $('<div>Ajax Request is Processing!</div>');
    $.ajax({
      method:"POST",
      url:"insert_msg.php",
      data: frm.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function(){
        frm.hide();
        frm.insertAfter(message);
      },
      success: function (data) {
        message.remove();
        frm.show();
      }
    });
  });

  function scroll() {
    $(".msg_history").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "slow");
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either keep action or onclick.

If you keep onclick then change the type to button. It should fix the issue

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Explain why you think this should help

Comment: Okay. When you will click on submit button which one will call insert msg or ref. What you are trying to achieve, is not correct. You are calling two action on a single click.

Comment: @Nytraxaqw did you remove onclick or action?